# Is a Tensorflow 3d convolution layer with kernel depth equal to depth equivalent to a 2d convolution layer?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, convolution

To further explain the title, I am passing a series of single channel pictures into a convolution network and am comparing and contrasting conv3d versus conv2d.  There are two possible setups I'm considering:

Setup 1 is using a conv2d layer with each picture input as a single channel. Input dimensions [batch_size,width,height,num_pictures].  Kernal Dimensions [width, height], and Stride [1,1].  Valid Padding.

Setup 2 is using a conv3d layer with each picture as the "depth" component of the kernal used for each picture.  Input dimensions [batch_size, num_pictures, width, height, 1].  Kernal Dimensions [num_pictures, width, height]. Stride [1,1,1]. Valid padding.

The way I see it, 2d convolution networks consider all channels of a given input; so is there functionally any difference between the two above setups pragmatically and performance wise?

Comment: Please don't tag spam. This question clearly has absolutely nothing to do with CUDA programming, so why add the tag?

Comment: Only was tagged with Cuda because of possible performance related details; tensorflow is primarily run on cuda.  Regardless, I appreciate the proper untagging, thank you.